# Highcharts: Different tick interval in the same axis

Tags: highcharts

I have a series that is composed of:

1. Daily values, until a certain date
2. 6-monthly values, from that date
   onward

[image: Some data example]

I'd like to increase the tick interval **exclusively** for the second part of the chart, so I can compact the data. To be clear, I want **the same space** that represents **one month** on the left side of the chart to represent **6 months** on the right side.

[image: Some data, as I want to see it]

I'm not sure if Highcharts allows this... I think there can be two different approaches:

1. Create two series with two different axis and set one axis after the other
2. Set different tickInterval for the same axis.

Using tickPositions and tickPositioner I've only managed to show more or less ticks, but always keeping their position on the time axis.

This is my code:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
  zoomType: 'xy',
  animation: false
},
    title: {
    text: 'Some data'
},
    legend: {
        verticalAlign: 'bottom',
        borderWidth: 0
    },
    xAxis: {
        type : 'datetime',
        tickInterval: 30 * 24 * 3600 * 1000,
        labels: {
            useHTML: true,
            rotation: -90
        },
        dateTimeLabelFormats: { // don't display the dummy year
            month: '%b-%y',
            year: '%Y'
        },
        plotLines: [{
            color: 'gray',
            dashStyle: 'longdashdot',
            value: 1536278400000,
            width: 1,
            label: {
                text: 'Selected Date'
            }
        }]
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: null
        },
        maxZoom: 0.1
    },
    series: jsonData
```

});

[Here's a jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s3uq0ady/7/) with a subset of my original data.

Which would be the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Highcharts does not allow it by default, but you can use a workaround. You can create two xAxis with right size proportion and two series, like in an example below:

```
xAxis: [{
  type: 'datetime',
  endOnTick: false,
  tickInterval: 30 * 24 * 3600 * 1000,
  max: 1536278400000,
  width: '65%',
  labels: {
    useHTML: true,
    rotation: -90
  },
  dateTimeLabelFormats: { // don't display the dummy year
    month: '%b-%y',
    year: '%Y'
  },
  plotLines: [{
    color: 'gray',
    dashStyle: 'longdashdot',
    value: 1536278400000,
    width: 1,
    label: {
      text: 'Selected Date'
    }
  }]
}, {
  min: 1536278400000,
  startOnTick: false,
  offset: 0,
  type: 'datetime',
  tickInterval: 180 * 24 * 3600 * 1000,
  labels: {
    useHTML: true,
    rotation: -90
  },
  dateTimeLabelFormats: { // don't display the dummy year
    month: '%b-%y',
    year: '%Y'
  },
  width: '35%',
  left: '65%'
}]
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/zxd4j5tn/

Comment: That's great! I had considered this approach but didn't know how to actually DO it. Thanks!

Comment: This solution doesn't play well with the zoom. I am considering disabling it, but is there anyway to get the two axis to work well with the zoom? Can't find any info on it...

Comment: Hi Rita Teixeira, This is a workaround, so it may have some shortcomings. It would be hard to handle zoom, because the solution uses two xAxis with right proportion and when zoom is fired this proportion is disturbed.

Comment: The zoom is not working properly when using multiple X axis. The result of zooming into the left section of the chart is not taking the whole chart width. Any workaround?

Comment: Hi @Mark, It requires a custom implementation, please check this example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/14x73mkt/ It's not fully completed, but shows how you can start.

Comment: Seems like it is more or less working when zooming into either series, but not when zooming into both, correct?

Comment: In my testing (my own code) with 2 X axis selecting both series works correctly without me doing anything. I just modified to this: else {
          // zoom on both axis
          // needs to recalculate positions, extremes, interal
          return true;
        } and works when selecting both series.

Comment: This code is a bit more stable: https://jsfiddle.net/k6qvnz3f/